# how to write the code about login failed more than 5 times,ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i already have the crm_member_list table and also can successfully login ,now i want to add a column to crm_member_list table called "failed_times" to record the failed times.when the failed_times more than 5 times.user account is locked.

i define a method called add_failed_times in the crm_member_list model.

```
  def self.add_failed_times(mbr_id)
     member = find_by_mbr_id(mbr_id)    
     failed_times = member.failed_times.to_i+1          
  end
```

in the session controller,

```
  def create      
    member = CrmMemberList.authenticate(params[:session][:mbr_id],params[:session][:password])    
    if member.nil? 
      user= CrmMemberList.find_by_mbr_id(params[:session][:mbr_id])
      if user.nil?
        flash.now[:error] = "Invalid passport/password combination."
        @title = "User nil"
        render 'new'
      else
        times = CrmMemberList.add_failed_times(params[:session][:mbr_id])
        if times.to_i=1 
          user.failed_times=times  
          user.save    
          flash.now[:error] = "Invalid passport/password combination."
          @title = "Less than 6"
          render 'new'        
        else
          @title ="Locked"
          render 'failed'  
        end   
      end             
    else
      sign_in member
      redirect_to member  
    end                             
  end
```

How can i resolve this problem?
thanks

the save is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing the save is false due to some validation error. Probably the password and password confirmation don't match.  You can call

```
user.save(:validates => false)
```

which bypasses the validation.

If you're unsure what the error is, after you've called `user.save`, you can output

```
user.errors
```

To get the errors that are stopping your save.

Comment: i am so confused that when i new a user in console, such as 'user=CrmMemberList.new' then 'user.mbr_id="G12121212",user.password="12345678",user.save',these operation is sucessful,and all the create and add_failed_times both success and can save the data to database,but when i close the console and open again,this time i find the user by mbr_id,the following operations are the same, but this time when i save ,the error is password can not be blank(PS: in the database ,i dont have password column,i save the encrypt_password in the database, the password is just a attr_accesor).

Comment: You must have a validation in your user model to check for presence of password, this means that when you create the user, the model checks that there is a password (unencrypted) in the model. This is a virtual attr and not saved to the DB. When you retrieve this record this virtual attribute is not present so the validation fails. I'm guessing the reason for this is to not allow a user to be modified without them inputting their password first, which is essentially what you're doing. As it's in the session create method you could just add user.password = params[:password] or similar

Comment: Hi,Yule,thanks so much, you are correct, i have a validation for the presence of password,but i still can not save,i think the problem is that it is updating not creating a new record, so i should change to update action.I will try and check if it is right. and there is another question,when i have two table,both have composite keys,no id column,and the relationship is one to many,such as comment belongs to post,when i want to create a new comment form '<%= form_for([@post,@post.comments.build]) do |f| %>',there will be a error show that no attribute comment_id,how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

What about using a gem to handle the whole authentication stuff (including [account locking](http://rubydoc.info/github/binarylogic/authlogic/master/Authlogic/Session/BruteForceProtection/Config)) automagically : https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic ?